# SVG/CSS Animation not rotating

Tags: svg

I copied a code snippet from here: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/svg-css-animation
but I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="#f7f3d1" css-transition: all 1s ease; css-animation: rotate 5s infinite linear />
</svg>
```

Comment: Well a SVG is rendered, so add some more details like what's not working. Please see [ask].

Comment: I"ve removed the codepen link since this can be seen here on SO using a snippet.

Comment: The animation is supposed to rotate and not just stay in one place.

Comment: I changed the title since it wasn't quite correct

Comment: I think you need to read another blog. The syntax that one suggests is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the snippet already shows that the syntax is invalid:

```
css-transition: all 1s ease; css-animation: rotate 5s infinite linear
```

Inline styling uses `key=value` format.

---

If you don't want to specify any keypoints or so, you can use the SVG `<animateTransform>` element to rotate the `<rect>`

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="#f7f3d1">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="1s" from="0 40 40" to="360 40 40"  repeatDur="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, 0stone0, your snippet worked!